Docker image for raspberry pi, cannot find manifest
I'm trying to deploy my java application to my raspberry pi.
I've set up a Github Actions workflow which compiles and builds an image and pushes it to DockerHub.
However, when I try to run it on my raspberry I get:

Warning: the requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested.

This makes sense, I've tried to use this image arm64v8/openjdk:21
but when I run the pipeline it says

arm64v8/openjdk:21: no match for platform in manifest sha256:585e107723f938041e7ac695f607e0523ae6e8c3a3955573ed111969f523745c: not found

I've looked on StackOverflow and tried setting the experimental flag to true in the docker engine, I'm also on linux containers.
This is my github actions pipeline:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '21'

      - name: build_with_maven
        run: mvn clean package

      - name: login_to_docker
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_KEY }}

      - name: push_to_docker
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./DockerfileRaspBerry
          push: true
          tags: hidden

With DockerFileRaspBerry:
FROM arm64v8/openjdk:21
MAINTAINER Phi
EXPOSE 80
COPY target/portfolio.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

What could I try differently here?

If you use docker to build images then you need to a.) run your build on the target platform or b.) enable cross-platform emulation to do the same. Simply switching the source the root image while still building on amd64 won't magically build an ARM image. The second message tells you that your (AMD64 based) build can't find an image in armv64v8/openjdk that it can run (because that only contains ARM images).

Ah that make a lot of sense, I run it ubuntu-latest using github actions, is there an option for arm64v8? Or how would you suggest I enable cross platform emulation?

Here's one question on that topic. Personally especially for Java apps, I'd try to switch to something like jib, because it's a much more lightweight process of building images for Java apps: it can easily build images for multiple architectures without having to be able to run on those architectures. This also avoids the quite severe performance penalty of having to emulate one architecture on another.

There is a --platform option on docker build where you can specify the platform of the image. I don't know if Github actions support building for Arm though.

Thank you @JoachimSauer, with help of the link you've provided I've solved the issue. I now use a similar approach as the linked article.
I will dive into Jib, thank you.
